# opencart error when upgrade to 2.1.0.1 version

Tags: mysqli, opencart, opencart2.x

I want upgrade from OpenCart version 2.0.3.1 to 2.1.0.1.

I've done an upgrade in the normal way as upgrade process previously. but upgrade this time is different from previous ones. some error show. I've tried several ways in OpenCart forum but did not find a way out

1. add `define('DB_PORT', '3306');` in to the config.php
2. I created table in my opencart database manually :

   ```
    CREATE TABLE `oc_cart` (
       `cart_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `session_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
       `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `recurring_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `option` text NOT NULL,
       `quantity` int(5) NOT NULL,
       `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`),
       KEY `cart_id` (`customer_id`,`session_id`,`product_id`,`recurring_id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
   ```

But, I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelToolOnline::whosonline() in
>   /home/...................
>   /modification/catalog/controller/common/footer.php on line 80

So can you help me how to upgrade opencart from 2.0.3.1 version to lastest (2.1.0.1) version without deleting my store data ?

sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: So you just created a table and got this error, right? Interesting !!

Comment: previously i created there were some errors because there are different tables with previous versions. my opencart version is 2.0.3.1. i want to upgrade to 2.1.0.1 version without deleting my data. can you give me a solution ?